# Entity Framework Core - How to have join table of many to many automatically update each respective reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Say I have a Person class with a property : `List<Person>`, called Friends. I want to have it so that adding a Person to the friend list of one class automatically adds it to the friend list of another Person.

According to documentation, to have a self-referencing many-to-many table you need to have two collections and EF will generate the join table PersonPerson.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name //...
    public List<Person>? FriendOf { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Person>? FriendWith { get; set; } = new();
}

public class PersonPerson
{
     //EF will create shadow Ids for both
     public Person p1;

     public Person p2;
}
```

I would like to do the following

```
person1 = new Person();
person2 = new Person();

person1.FriendsWith.Add(Person2));
```

and have person 2 also have person 1 added to their respective Lists.  I wasn't sure if EF could do this automatically or if I have to create a function to make 4 assignments to achieve what I want.

I've created a static method that does something like this, but if I'm expanding my application this introduces a lot of extra complexity.

Comment: What's the difference between `FriendOf` and `FriendWith`?

Comment: These are necessary for EF to recognize this as a self referencing relationship.  EF will automatically create a join table that has two columns, FriendOf and FriendWith to relate people.